# How can I SUMIF when two conditions need to be met?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have countries, values and status of the value and I want to sum the values when they relate to a particular country and are "Approved", what is the formula I would use?

Column A-C is the data and E-F is the total/summary. "FORMULA" is where I would like the formula to go.

```
DATA   A          B       C                   D          E
 1   Country    Value   Status              Country    Total Approved
 2   Germany    100     Approved            Germany    FORMULA
 3   France     150     Approved            Portugal   0
 4   UK         130     Not Approved        UK         100
 5   Portugal   200     Not Approved        France     150
 6   Germany    200     Approved
 7   Germany    300     Not Approved
 8   UK         100     Approved
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `SUMIFS()` here:

`=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2,C:C,"Approved")`

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but to improve the quality of your answer, could you add a brief explanation how it works and maybe add a reference? Giving references gives validity to your answer and encourages the OP to learn more.